# How to decide using lua_call() or lua_pcall()?

Tags: c, lua

I know the basic difference between `lua_call()` or `lua_pcall()`, the later one provides more error details.
Is there any other difference? How to decide which to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `lua_pcall` when you *need* to handle potential errors at that point in the code. Otherwise, use `lua_call` and let the error move up the call chain. No need to get paranoid using `lua_pcall` everywhere.

`lua_call` is faster than `lua_pcall`.

Just make sure there is at least one `lua_pcall` at the top or your app will panic and exit when finding any Lua errors.

Comment: What does "up the call chain" mean? Does this only apply if the call to lua code is being made from C code that was in turn called from lua? I'm a bit confused about when it would *ever* be valid to ignore errors when calling lua from C code, since lua can fail at any time (allocation error) and the C code will probably depend on the callee actually having performed the action it was called to perform...

Comment: @R.., it's ok to ignore errors in C code called from Lua because they will be reported in Lua. Most of the time you only have to protect the first call from C to Lua, eg when running a script.

Comment: "*Just make sure there is at least one lua_pcall at the top or your app*" This assumes that Lua is in charge of the application, rather than the application calling Lua to perform specific tasks.

Comment: Thank you @NicolBolas. You expressed what I was trying to get at better than I could.

Comment: @NicolBolas, strictly speaking, Lua is *never* in charge of the application: Lua must be started from C.

Comment: @lhf: "*Just make sure there is at least one lua_pcall at the top*" That means Lua is in charge. If there is a "top" where you have a single call into a Lua script, followed by that Lua script calling functions you have registered or other Lua scripts it accesses via various means, then Lua is in charge of the application. In applications where there is no "top", Lua is subordinate, acting as a means of implementing functions rather than deciding the overall behavior of the application. Yes, C must call into Lua; the question is *how this happens*. And if there's no "top", Lua's not in charge.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I'm with Luiz on this one. I don't see any relation between using lua_pcall and the design of the application? Basically what he's saying is that you should have at least one lua_pcall the same way you should have at least one catch clause in C++ somewhere in main to handle errors gracefully. It has nothing to do with the design of your application.

Comment: @W.B.: OK, let's say I am using Lua as a means of allowing some user-defined object creation. Users can write objects built in Lua for my application, which will use them in very well-defined ways. The "top" of my application, the main loop of the app, does not call `lua_pcall`. It doesn't call *any* Lua code, because it doesn't need to know that Lua is even *involved*. All it knows is that some objects exist and how to talk to them. It is those objects that call into Lua functions to do their work, but the application itself doesn't know or care about that.

Comment: @W.B.: So how does that fit with what he was saying? There's no "top" for me to use `lua_pcall` with. There are only the places where I interface with Lua. Is that how "top" is defined? Furthermore, having "one catch clause in C++ somewhere in main" only works if `main` is where your application begins (DLL/SO's don't use main) *and* you can "handle errors gracefully" from there. I've yet to see a serious C++ application that can truly "gracefully" handle *every* exception at the level of `main`. They may recover, but *only* due to the consistent use of RAII techniques.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I admit that catching all errors in main was a bit of an oversimplification, but I was just trying to present it in a simple way. In this example the top is clearly where you call from C/C++ into Lua. It doesn't matter if it's your main loop or some class 20 levels down the call stack. I'm not sure why you're arguing about the definitione of 'the top', as I am sure you know exactly what he meant. The same way one could argue about your definition of what is in chargé of the application (C or Lua). What's the point?

Comment: @W.B.: "*I'm not sure why you're arguing about the definitione of 'the top', as I am sure you know exactly what he meant*" No, I don't; that's why I'm asking about it. Depending on how your application works with Lua, the place where you call into it could be *anywhere* you could use `lua_call`. Do you know if a particular C/C++ function that calls into Lua does so at the behest of a Lua script? Unless your application is *designed a certain way* (namely, you call into Lua early and let Lua decide what happens next), you don't. So *every* `lua_call` should be a `lua_pcall`, as I suggested.

Comment: @NicolBolas, fair enough, **now** I know where you're coming from. But I don't think that was very clear in your initial comment (or perhaps it's just me ;). And I was not arguing validity of your suggestion (well, I always use `lua_pcall`).

Answer (score 5):

Use `lua_pcall` in all situation unless you have some ***specific performance issues***. Then use `lua_call`. But again, only if you have *profiled* your application and discovered a *specific* performance issue that `lua_call` will alleviate.

If a Lua error is thrown by Lua during a `lua_call`, your application is pretty much hosed. So you need to make sure that `lua_pcall` is used where possible.

Comment: I disagree. The point is not performance: it's where and when the error is reported.

Comment: @lhf: Yes, and generally speaking, errors should be reported and handled *as soon as possible*. This isn't C++ with exception handling and RAII here; a longjmp to the "top" of your application will likely leak pretty much every object you have ever created that *isn't* connected to Lua. The ability to continue on with the application after such an error is basically impossible.